# D365: Hide specific field(s) on contact "merge record" popup form

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-365

I want to customize the below merge record form.

[image: merge record form]

It should hide the specified field and I should be able to enable those fields from JavaScript.

My question here is

- Is it really possible to modify this form?
- Can I enable/disable the value selection option in this form?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately this **Merge form** cannot be customized like writing scripts, show/hide controls or options. Not even a form designer.

The rendered **Merge form** will show all the fields from the last visited form of that entity, based on the user access.

I have not verified this, but if there are scripts for `onChange` event on any field then **Bulk Edit form** won’t show that field, not sure if the same rule is applied to **Merge form** also.

Comment: Also read: http://www.crmconsultants.co.uk/considerations-for-merging-duplicate-records-in-dynamics-crm/